# C# Detect clipboard paste WITH HOOK

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, hook

Is possible to globally intercept paste events on Windows and block depending on the target process, with a hook that works in C# WinForms Any CPU build?

I thought about putting a hook in [GetClipboardData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms649039(v=vs.85).aspx) or wait for WM_PASTE messages.

My first attempt was [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), but another look discouraged me.

[MSDN says:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318804/how-to-set-a-windows-hook-in-visual-c-.net)

> Global hooks are not supported in the .NET Framework
>   Except for the WH_KEYBOARD_LL low-level hook and the WH_MOUSE_LL low-level hook, you cannot implement global hooks in the Microsoft .NET Framework. To install a global hook, a hook must have a native DLL export to inject itself in another process that requires a valid, consistent function to call into. This behavior requires a DLL export. The .NET Framework does not support DLL exports. Managed code has no concept of a consistent value for a function pointer because these function pointers are proxies that are built dynamically.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Did you saw the article date? Article ID: 318804 - Last Review: Mar 19, 2009 - Revision: 1

Comment: you need *Creating a Clipboard Format Listener* by call [`AddClipboardFormatListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649033.aspx) -

Comment: Hi @RbMm, so, how can I detect when an application gets the clipboard data when using AddClipboardFormatListener? Is not this called just when an user copy data?

Comment: the [`WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649021.aspx) will be sent to your window when the contents of the clipboard have changed

Comment: Is not this called just when an user copy data? I would like to intercept when the user pastes the data.

Comment: @Vinicius There is simply no system event or clipboard hook for what you are looking for. The clipboard only notifies when new data is placed on the clipboard, not when data is retrieved. So you have to resort to per-process API hooking, and you can't do that easily in .NET. And `GetClipboardData` isn't the only API for retrieving data. For instance, `OleGetClipboard`.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau, I am very grateful for your feedback. This answers my question. Could you post it as an answer? I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ideal solution to detect paste event. Like RbMm said WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE will be sent only when the content in the clipboard is changed. (copy or cut). WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD is sent during a paste action but only if the content in the clipboard was added using a cut action.

But you can achieve this by implementing a file system filter driver.